# Get --launch-profile value at runtime .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I'm running my xUnit tests and I have set up different profiles (different devs, stage, prod). I'm able to get the launchSettings.json and load the profile settings. But because I can't get the current profile at runtime, I'm not able to differentiate them.

Is there a way that I can get the profile value passed on the arguments `dotnet run --launch-profile <MY_PROFILE_NAME>` at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

### linux

With *ps* command we can get command of a process given its *pid*. So we'll have to get *pid* of a process and extract its command line arguments.

```cs
// when you execute 'dotnet run' command, actuall program is being executed
// as a child proess of the 'dotnet' command, so we'll have to extract parent
// 'pid' of process which is being reported by 'Environment.ProcessId'
// 'ps --pid 123 -f --format ppid --no-headers' will report parent process id 
// of process with pid 123
var getParentIdProcess = Process
    .Start(new ProcessStartInfo("ps", $"--pid {Environment.ProcessId} -f --format ppid --no-headers") 
            { RedirectStandardError = true, RedirectStandardOutput = true, });

getParentIdProcess.WaitForExit();

var parentProcessId = getParentIdProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    .TrimEnd()
    .TrimStart();

// when we know parent 'pid' we can extract command line of it via the same
// 'ps' command. 
// 'ps --pid 123 --format args --no-headers' will return 'dotnet run --launch-profile ...'
var getCommandOfAProcess = Process
        .Start(new ProcessStartInfo("ps", $"--pid {parentProcessId} --format args --no-headers")
                { RedirectStandardError = true, RedirectStandardOutput = true, });

getCommandOfAProcess.WaitForExit();

var arguments = getCommandOfAProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    .Split(" ");

// extract value of --launch-profile flag
var launchProfileValue = arguments[Array.IndexOf(arguments, "--launch-profile") + 1];
```

### windows

To make it work on windows, you'll have to do some adjustments, there is no *ps* command there, so we'll use *wmic* command instead. But the general idea is the same.

Getting parent process id:

```cs
var getParentIdProcess = Process
    .Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $" /c wmic process where (processid={Environment.ProcessId}) get parentprocessid")
    { RedirectStandardError = true, RedirectStandardOutput = true, });

getParentIdProcess.WaitForExit();

var parentProcessId = getParentIdProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    .TrimEnd()
    .TrimStart()
    .Split("\n")
    .Last();
```

Getting command line arguments of the process:

```cs
var getCommandOfAProcess = Process
        .Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c wmic path win32_process where \"processid like {parentProcessId}\"  get commandline")
        { RedirectStandardError = true, RedirectStandardOutput = true, });

getCommandOfAProcess.WaitForExit();

var arguments = getCommandOfAProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    .TrimEnd()
    .TrimStart()
    .Split("\n")
    .Last()
    .Split(" ");
```